# Parse CSV data from REST API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have implemented a sample application in PHP Laravel that consumes data from rest api with data format csv.
The code is as follows:

```
 public function index() {

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $request = $client->get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv");
        $response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
```

I want to parse this data in readable format and loop it as for each property. Can someone please help me?

Comment: please share to output of `$response`

Comment: Here you are: https://pastebin.com/HM4Rxz0P

Comment: Your response is not a `csv.`  It is just a string with commas

Comment: So, how can I obtain data for each respective property?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a CSV parser for this. Try with https://github.com/thephpleague/csv